# How to get size of data recieved SocketChannel

Tags: java, socketchannel

I'm writing a server for my app, which must get data from client and do smth. The communication is done using `SocketChannel`, but there is a problem: i only can read previously specified number of bytes from it (as of javadoc for `channel.read(ByteBuffer dst)`)

> An attempt is made to read up to r bytes from the channel, where r is the number of bytes remaining in the buffer

Is there any way to get size of data, that is currently in the channel and read all it into the `byte[]`?

Comment: You can't do that. Just use avarage buffer, and use value, returned by "read" to know how much data just read

Comment: @user996142 That is entirely equivalent to doing what you have just said can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

> there is a problem: i only can read previously specified number of bytes from it

That's not correct.

> (as of javadoc for `channel.read(ByteBuffer dst)`)
>
> An attempt is made to read up to r bytes from the channel, where r is the number of bytes remaining in the buffer

You've missed the words 'up to'. There is no problem. If one byte is available, one byte will be read, regardless of the amount of room left in the `ByteBuffer`.

> Is there any way to get size of data, that is currently in the channel and read all it into the `byte[]`?

That's exactly what happens. The amount of data 'currently in the channel' == the amount of data that will be read provided the room left in the ByteBuffer >= the size of the data in the socket receive buffer, and that will be the value returned by `read()`.

Comment: I have not missed this words, but in this way, I should to create a buffer with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` capacity if I want 100% read all data from channel, and it is not a good idea. But I already done it by sending data size in first 4 bytes.

Comment: So your question was incorrectly expressed. 'All data currently in the channel' can only mean 'all the data currently in the socket receive buffer'. If you mean instead 'all the data that will ever be sent over the channel' it is of course potentially infinite.

Answer (score -1):

I think is there is none. You have to manage this by yourself. Are you using serialized objects or did you create your own protocol?

Comment: I'm sending an object, serialized to `byte[]` by default java serialization. I know, that i can send arrray size, but may be there is a way to not do it myself?

Comment: Have look at my blog, I had to do this while sending serialized objects via UDP: https://ulrichbuschbaum.wordpress.com/2015/04/06/sending-an-object-via-udp-multicast-using-java/

Comment: Your blog contains numerous errors, starting with the bizarre claim that UDP's lack of streaming is due to Java, and the code ignoring the length returned by `receive()`, and the sender joining the multicast group when it doesn't need to. Nothing there that answers this question.

Comment: You misunderstood this. It's due to the protocol, not Java. Perhaps I should have explained this more clearly. :)

Comment: I misunderstood nothing. I know what it's due to. That's how I knew it was an error. When you state 'In Java there’s a little problem regarding the usage of UDP ... ' you are uttering a mistake. Certainly you need to express it more clearly.